# How to send a signal to all the PTransform objects running on Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm now implementing an Apache beam application running on Dataflow which consumes data from a Cloud PubSub, transforms the format of them and sends the results to another Cloud PubSub. It loads the definitions of the streaming data which describes the names and types of keys and how each data should be transformed. The definitions are stored in GCS and loaded when the applications starts.

My question is that the way to update the definitions and notify the changes of each PTransform object running on the data flow. Is it possible to do that online? or do we have to drain and recreate the dataflow app?